# Enable right click on WordPress site

Tags: functions, javascript

I can not right click on my [site](https://www..ir) and I don't know why!

Is there any function to enable right click on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something WordPress is doing but probably your theme.  Perhaps it's an attempt to get people to not download your images or code, this is basically useless and doesn't prevent anything like that.

Your theme might be using something similar to this...

`document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());`

Try searching your theme files for `contextmenu` and see what you can find.